# Tailwind font-weight doesn't work when using custom font

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, font-family

I am using Tailwind v3.2.0 in a Vue3 project.

I changed the font family in the tailwind's configuration file :

```js
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Poppins', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans]
      },
    }
  }
```

I also imported the font in my `index.html` file :

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">`

I am now trying to use the tailwind font-weight utilities from https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-weight but there is no effect.

I tried removing the fontFamily from tailwind's configuration file, and the font-weight properties are then working fine.

I'm pretty new to tailwind and still learning, am I missing something ?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can use a CDN font + fonts at the same time. I recommend that you install it locally (it will be better on every aspects anyway), then you should probably be able to do that just fine.

Comment: With Google Fonts you have to specify the font weights you want to use. With the URL you've used (https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins), only the Regular (400) weight will be loaded.

To load more weights, you can specify them in the URL. This example will load the Regular, Medium, and Bold weights: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;700" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @CraigE good point! Even tho, I'm not sure how do you specific the various _italic_ etc variants. Plus, it will always be better to host it locally anyway.

Comment: Both your solutions work, thank you! I'll go for the local download solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [google-webfonts-helper tool](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts) to download your fonts locally and get all the benefits in terms of latency + ease of use regarding any debugging.

Then, Tailwind will be able to work properly with it.
In case you have any issues, I recommend that you double check your network tab or use Firefox (that browser is pretty good at debugging font issues).

[Fonts Ninja](https://www.fonts.ninja/) is also quite nice to quickly debug the font you currently have. Be careful, Chrome uses locally installed fonts so it can be a bit tricky (Firefox doesn't have this issue).